# WebUsb cutting Thermal print receipt

Tags: printing, thermal-printer, printers, webusb

I'm working on a point-of-sale web application 
I was able to detect and print from the web using this code

```html
<html>
<body>
    <textarea id="printContent"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" onclick="connectAndPrint()" value="Print"/>
    <P>Type text into box and click on submit button.
    <script>
    var device;



    function setup(device) {
        return device.open()
        .then(() => device.selectConfiguration(1))
        .then(() => device.claimInterface(0))
    }

    function print() {
        var string = document.getElementById("printContent").value + "\n";
        var encoder = new TextEncoder();
        var data = encoder.encode(string);
        device.transferOut(1, data)
        .catch(error => { console.log(error); })

    }


    function connectAndPrint() {
        if (device == null) {
            
            navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [{}]})
            .then(selectedDevice => {
                device = selectedDevice;
                console.log(device);
                return setup(device);
            })
            .then(() => print())
            .catch(error => { console.log(error); })
        }
        else
            print();
    }

    navigator.usb.getDevices()
    .then(devices => {
        if (devices.length > 0) {
            device = devices[0];
            return setup(device);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => { console.log(error); });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

my question is how I can send command to cut the receipt

**Note**: I used [Zidag](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) software to add webusb certification to the printer
this changed the signature of the device and make it invisible in the control panel under View Devices and Printers
so my printer is not there and I can't make a setting to auto cut after it's finished

Answer (score 0):

To cut after printing you need to add the cut command to the end of the text being printed. The command will depend on the type of printer you are using. For example, if your printer uses the ESC/POS command set developed by Epson you can find the documentation on cutting commands here:

https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=87

Note, these commands may require putting raw bytes and ASCII control codes into the data sent to the device in the `transferOut()` call. For example, the command listed as "GS V 0" would be "\x1D\x56\x00" where the "GS" character is 0x1D in hexadecimal and the parameter 0 is a literal zero byte rather than the digit "0".

Comment: thank you,
you answered this perfectly I appreciate it but is there any workaround if I don't know the cut command of my current printer ? it's not available online like Epson printers

Comment: You should be able to get this documentation by reaching out to the printer manufacturer.

Comment: @ReillyGrant Could you please give us the reference code for transferOut() method .